# SmtpException: Server does not support secure connections

Tags: asp.net, smtp

In my website whenever a user logs in admin will receive a mail with login details. From past many years i was using smtp.gmail.com for sending mails, now i wished to change it. So i was trying to send mail using new smtp credentials given by my new mail client.  Now when i use there details to send a mail i get and exception saying

**System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Server does not support secure connections.**

I have contacted the support team for help to check my credentials but they have tested my credentials and replied everything is fine. Below is my code which i am using to set smtp details.

```
<smtp from="info@store36.com">
<network host="smtp.falconide.com" password="" port="587" userName=""/>
</smtp>
```

I have tried both 25 and 587 ports, my EnableSsl is set to true. Please help me.

Comment: Post your own answer as the solution

Answer (score 26):

you might want to set `EnableSsl` to `false` or

```
<add key="EnableSsl" value="false"/>
```

if your setting is on `Web.config` or `App.config`.

Comment: This could be a security problem. Could you explain why its not a problem?

Comment: that means you should just update your SmtpClient instance something like
     SmtpClient.EnableSsl = false
The error is just too explicit and it means your host is not secure(https - SSL)

Comment: This is not an answer. I don't understand how people can upvote an answer like this. This disables ssl.
I am trying to send through the 365 dedicated connector, so unauthenticated. But I want (actually need) to use ssl. On my local machine it works. On the production server, I have this ridiculous error message (which server doesn't support secure connections? Microsoft's? of course not. Mine? I use ssl for many other things).